# If statement inside an sql query

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a function in PL/SQL which has two SQL statements in it, they are as follows :

```
select access_level into v_access from users where user_ID = APEX_UTIL.get_username( APEX_UTIL.get_current_user_id );
```

and

```
for row in ( select distinct sub_category_lu
                  , f_get_display('SUB_CATEGORY', sub_category_lu) display
                 from files
                 where active = 'Y'
                 and publish_date <= sysdate
                 and category_lu =  p_category
      and key in ( 0, snl_key )
      order by substr(sub_category_lu,1,2)
      ) loop
```

Now based on the output from the first sql statement, I want to add another `'and'` condition in the second sql statement which is in the for loop.

like if v_access is 'xyz' then I want to add a condition in the for loop sql statement as

```
AND sub_category_lu NOT LIKE '03%' AND sub_category_lu NOT LIKE '04%'
```

else dont add this condition and keep the loop as above. How can I add an if statement according to this in the loop. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding only:

```
(...) AND (v_access != 'xyz' 
          OR (sub_category_lu NOT LIKE '03%' AND sub_category_lu NOT LIKE '04%'))
```